# Thread memory address greater than physical RAM

Tags: java, multithreading, out-of-memory

I'm trying to understand the memory map I'm seeing as provided by [Java NMT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr007.html). I'm trying to decide whether I'm running into the issue described in [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/running-on-a-64bit-platform-and-still-running-out-of-memory) blog post (TL;DR - the Java heap is too close to the top of non-heap memory used for things like threads so when I try to create more threads I get an OOM Error).

Here's part of the output for `jcmd {pid} VM.native_memory detail scale=MB` :

```
Virtual memory map:

[0x00000000c2400000 - 0x0000000100000000] reserved 988MB for Java Heap from
    [0x00007fc34a953f12] ReservedSpace::initialize(unsigned long, unsigned long, bool, char*, unsigned long, bool)+0xc2
    [0x00007fc34a9548ee] ReservedHeapSpace::ReservedHeapSpace(unsigned long, unsigned long, bool, char*)+0x6e
    [0x00007fc34a92199b] Universe::reserve_heap(unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x8b
    [0x00007fc34a7d7d44] ParallelScavengeHeap::initialize()+0x84

[0x0000000100000000 - 0x0000000140000000] reserved 1024MB for Class from
    [0x00007fc34a953f12] ReservedSpace::initialize(unsigned long, unsigned long, bool, char*, unsigned long, bool)+0xc2
    [0x00007fc34a95414b] ReservedSpace::ReservedSpace(unsigned long, unsigned long, bool, char*, unsigned long)+0x1b
    [0x00007fc34a735320] Metaspace::allocate_metaspace_compressed_klass_ptrs(char*, unsigned char*)+0x40
    [0x00007fc34a7377ff] Metaspace::global_initialize()+0x4cf


[0x00007fc2e2d08000 - 0x00007fc2e2e09000] reserved and committed 1MB for Thread Stack from
    [0x00007fc34a906304] JavaThread::run()+0x24
    [0x00007fc34a7b6ea8] java_start(Thread*)+0x108

[0x00007fc2e2e09000 - 0x00007fc2e2f0a000] reserved and committed 1MB for Thread Stack from
    [0x00007fc34a906304] JavaThread::run()+0x24
    [0x00007fc34a7b6ea8] java_start(Thread*)+0x108

[0x00007fc2e2f0a000 - 0x00007fc2e300b000] reserved and committed 1MB for Thread Stack from
    [0x00007fc34a906304] JavaThread::run()+0x24
    [0x00007fc34a7b6ea8] java_start(Thread*)+0x108
```

That starting location (0x00007fc2e2d08000) is at ~140GB but I only have 4GB of physical memory on the machine. How can I have a thread located in memory in the range 0x00007fc2e2d08000 - 0x00007fc2e2e09000?

Is it really simply a case of 0x00007fc2e2d08000 being a virtual memory address?

How can I locate the real address of the thread to verify I'm not running into the issue described in [the blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/running-on-a-64bit-platform-and-still-running-out-of-memory)?

Here's my `top` output too by the way - it shows we're not using any swap space so the only memory used is indeed the physical memory.

```
top - 11:08:07 up 5 days, 25 min,  3 users,  load average: 0.05, 0.12, 0.09
Tasks: 131 total,   1 running, 130 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s): 10.3 us,  1.8 sy,  0.0 ni, 87.5 id,  0.2 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.0 si,  0.2 st
KiB Mem:   4044792 total,  3789788 used,   255004 free,    63868 buffers
KiB Swap:        0 total,        0 used,        0 free.  1575428 cached Mem
```

Comment: "Is it really simply a case of 0x00007fc2e2d08000 being a virtual memory address?"  Yes.

Comment: All processes outside of the OS kernel deal exclusively in virtual memory. Only the OS itself can access physical memory directly.

Comment: @StephenC - Thanks for confirming. Do you know how I might verify whether my memory layout could be susceptible to the issue described in the blog post? I don't know how to do that if I can't determine how much space is before the memory allocated to the heap.